# a problem with using a function and parameters to create a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I could use some help with this problem. I need to make a function that creates a dictionary with 4 parameters and a key that increase every entry of this dictionary. So far I have this:

```py
def create_db(temp, rain, humidity, wind):
    weather = {}
    n = 0
    for i in (temp, rain, humidity, wind):
        n = n + 1
        weather[n] = (temp, rain, humidity, wind)
    return weather

temp = [1, 5, 3]
rain = [0, 30, 100]
humidity = [30, 50, 65]
wind = [3, 5, 7]
weather = create_db(temp, rain, humidity, wind)
print(weather)
```

The problem with this code is that it prints:

```
{1: (1, 0, 30, 3), 2: (1, 0, 30, 3), 3: (1, 0, 30, 3), 4: (1, 0, 30, 3)}
```

It only put the first value for the list in all for them.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

temp, rain etc are lists. You need to reference the element in each list - i.e.

```
weather[n] = (temp[n], rain[n], humidity[n], wind[n])
```

You also don't mean `for i in (temp, rain, humidity, wind)` - this will be 4, because there are 4 list variables there. Instead use the length of one of the lists, e.g.:

```
for n in range(len(temp)):
```

That way you also don't need to increment `n`.

Comment: `for n in range(len(temp))`

Comment: Thanks - have fixed it. I usually spend most days telling people to 'not' use `for i in range(len(x))` combined with `x[i]` when they just want the elements from the list, so obviously my brain refused to type it here!

Answer (score 1):

I'll point out that while your method is not 'wrong' (after the fix is applied), a more Pythonic way of doing this dispenses with the need to use indices altogether:

```
def create_db(temp, rain, humidity, wind):
    return {n: vals for n, vals in enumerate(zip(temp, rain, humidity, wind), 1)}
```

or the even-more-streamlined version:

```
def create_db(temp, rain, humidity, wind):
    return dict(enumerate(zip(temp, rain, humidity, wind), 1))
```

Comment: You don't even need the dict comprehension; `dict(enumerate(...))` is sufficient.

Comment: @chepner Yes, thanks! Added alternate but left the original to show some nuts-and-bolts.